# How to position a widget to the bottom of navigation bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, position, bottomnavigationview

I need to position a container of height 5.0 and infinity width in a bottom navigation bar item to the bottom of the bar. But there is a gap between the current position and the bottom navigation bar. May I know how to fix this?

[image]
[image: enter image description here`]

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            activeIcon: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'HOME',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: '#FFFFFF'.toColor(),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    color: '#D86300'.toColor(),
                    height: 5.0,
                    width: double.infinity),
              ],
            ),
            icon: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'HOME',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: '#FFFFFF'.toColor(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(),
            ]),
            label: 'HOME',
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use padding for this and set the padding as much as you want

Comment: I tried adding Padding but theres is no change in the position.. `Padding(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.all(0), 
                    child: Container(
                        color: '#D86300'.toColor(),
                        height: 5.0,
                        width: double.infinity),
                  ),`

Comment: you are setting padding to 0 try to set it  Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),

Comment: Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(10) is not helping....any other suggestions please?